# Error: Unexpected request: POST karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, karma-mocha

I am getting the below error when i run my test cases, `Error: Unexpected request: POST data/json/api.json`

```
it("should $watch value", function(){
      var request = '/data/json/api.json';
      $httpBackend.expectPOST(request).respond(200);

      var iplScore = 10;
      var controller = new controller(iplScore);
      $scope.cricketScore = 0;
      $scope.$digest();
      $scope.cricketScore = 1;
      assert.equal(iplScore, 0);
 });
```

Below is my controller code:

```
$scope.$watch("cricketScore", function(newValue, oldValue) {
     $scope.iplScore = oldValue;
});
```

Can anyone help me out why am i am getting the above error, even though i have mocked the api via `$httpBackend`

Comment: Could you show your complete test and how you've mocked the api calls?

Comment: @alecxe: there is no more code.. this is how i have mocked up my api calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *have not mocked* your API calls. Put the following into the `beforeEach()`:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    $httpBackend.when('POST', '/data/json/api.json').respond(200, {
        status: "success"
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i get an error now AssertionError: expected 10 to equal 0... is the $scope.$digest() not calling cricketScore variable?

Comment: @ShankarGuru I think you have to call the `$digest()` every time you change a variable in the scope. Please see this blogpost, should clear things up: http://juristr.com/blog/2014/11/learning-ng-testing-watch-expressions/. Thanks.